# div container floats outside of parent container

Tags: html, css

I´m currently trying to create some kind of tab component. It all works fine, if the text inside the label tags is short enough to get displayed inside the content div. If the text is too long, the text gets shortened with ellipsis. But if this happens, the x icon floats out of the parent div.

How to fix this behaviour, so that the x stays in the component div **without** limiting the labels to a fix size? the reason behind this is, that the icon shcould only appear, if the mouse is hovered over the tab. otherwise the label should reach all the way to the right side. I know how to to this stuff. The only problem currently is the falsy displayed x icon.

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.component {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.line {
    width: 2px;
    min-width: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 5px;
}

.label {
  line-height: 13px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #c4c7cc;
    width: 100%;
}

.icon {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  Example with short Text
  <div class="component">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class=label>aaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class=label>bbbbbbbb</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">X</div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  Example with long Text
  <div class="component">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class=label>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class=label>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnnnnnnnnnnnnnn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Position the X absolutely to the top right of your container

Comment: @Huangism Can you please give me a code sample in CSS (with copy snippet to answer)?

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/1xtyorqw/ component has position relative, and the x has position absolute, top 0 right 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Need to add overflow: hidden; On the .content class

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.component {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.line {
    width: 2px;
    min-width: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.label {
  line-height: 13px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #c4c7cc;
    width: 100%;
}

.icon {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  Example with short Text
  <div class="component">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class=label>aaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class=label>bbbbbbbb</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">X</div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  Example with long Text
  <div class="component">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class=label>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class=label>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbnnnnnnnnnnnnnn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simple and beautiful! I like your answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float the `.icon` element, it's better to position it as `absolute` (look at my css code below).
To do this the `.component` division has to be positioned as `relative`. Once you've positioned the container as `relative` it will be the reference for the coordinates for the `absolute` positioned element `.icon`.

```
.icon {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    color: black;
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
.component {

  position:relative; /*add this here*/

  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: When I use this CSS, my icon gets lost

Comment: I missed an o from position

Answer (score 0):

make the **component** position `relative` and the **icon** position `absolute` then set the right value to the icon .

like this:

```
.component {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
position:relative;
}

.icon {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute 
    right:2px;
}
```

to prevent text from appearing behind the **X** u can apply padding to the **component class**

```
.component{
padding-right:25px;
}
```